# Laravel subdomain variable issue

Tags: php, laravel

I have set up a subdomain routes with dynamic region subdomains and one static subdomain:

```
Route::domain('friends.' . env('APP_URL'))...

Route::domain('{region}.' . env('APP_URL'))...
```

Each of those two sections can call a controller which has region as parameter in index method:

```
public function getIndex($region)
```

The problem I have is that when controller is called from `{region}` segment, the variable gets filled. However if I go through first group it doesn't get recognized because I am forwarding an exact value instead.

Is there a way to map `friends` to `{region}` without doing some crazy quickfixes (like the one I'm doing currently)?

```
public function getIndex($region = null)
{
    if(!$region)
        $region = $this->regionService->getCurrentRegion();
    ...
}
```

Comment: changing the order doesn't work ?

Comment: If I changed the order the friends route would never be hit because it would enter the region group. Didn't want to complicate the explanation but region controller is calling index method, and friends controller is extending from that one, so it enters the original controller. But I need it to pass through friends controller nevertheless

Comment: i just read this "Is there a way to map friends to {region} "  i don't know if i understand the question

Comment: `getIndex()` is accepting `region` parameter. If the second route group is hit, the value gets filled with whatever is in the `{region}`. If the first group is hit the variable doesn't get filled because there is no `{ }` in the group, and it doesn't recognize friends as being a variable like `{region}`

Comment: Why not set the default value of `$region` to `friends` in your controller action?

Comment: Because in the process there is binding done, so that by the time the value gets to the controller, region provided actually gets pulled from DB and serves the whole object